# react-export-excel download from onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using "react-export-excel" lib to export json to excel.

This does work when clicking the button, but the process I want is:

- Add an onClick to the button without downloading the file straight away
- In the onClick event, show a loader
- Then download the file
- Then hide the loader when the file has downloaded

  ```
   <ExcelFile
       filename="Companies"
       element={<Button variant="dark-green" onClick={downloadCompanies}>Download</Button>}>
       <ExcelSheet data={companyExport.length > 0 && companyExport} name="Companies">


           <ExcelColumn label="Company Name" value="name"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Address" value="address"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Town" value="town"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Postcode" value="postcode"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Phone" value="telephone"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Website" value="website"/>
       </ExcelSheet>
  ```

```
    const downloadCompanies = e => {
        setDownloadingLoader(true)
        // Download file now
    }

    // Some event listener when the file has downloaded to hide loader
```

Does anyone know it's possible to achieve this with this library? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

not sure if you are still looking for an answer; I needed to achieve the same thing; what I think I am going to do, is having my own button other than the Download button listed above; onclick event of that button I would trigger the click event for the button attached with ExcelFile. You would obviously change

```
<ExcelFile
     filename="Companies"
     element={<Button variant="dark-green" onClick={downloadCompanies}>Download</Button>}>
     <ExcelSheet data={companyExport.length > 0 && companyExport} name="Companies">
```

to

```
<ExcelFile
     filename="Companies"
     element={<Button innerRef={this.buttonRef}></Button>}>
     <ExcelSheet data={companyExport.length > 0 && companyExport} name="Companies">
```

Then you can have your own button

```
<Button variant="dark-green" onClick={downloadCompanies}>Download</Button>
```

And in your downloadCompanies method you'll do following

```
if (this.buttonRef.current !== null) {
                this.buttonRef.current!.click();
            }
```

This is the best I think we can do with this component, let me know if you ended up with a better way or decided to use another component, thanks!

Comment: `innerRef` is a component instance property. I think you were looking for `ref` this allows you to access the DOM of the element because the `ref` attribute is a callback function that receives the underlying DOM of the component.

Comment: It worked.... Helped me a lot